# How to structure Svelte store of live stock quotes

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I am trying to maintain live stock quotes in a Svelte store so that on-screen bid and ask get updated in real-time.  I'm not sure how structure the store to hold the data to be reactive and efficient.  The data comes from a websocket and looks like this:

`{'symbol':'AAPL', 'bid':305.52, 'ask':305.55}`

My initial attempt looks like this:

```
import { readable, writable } from 'svelte/store';

export let quotes = {}

function addQuotes(sym) {
  const quote = writable({
    bid: 0,
    ask: 0
  });
  quotes[sym] = quote;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have a single map of quotes available throughout the SPA but have each individual quote update only its own symbol, not the entire page, with each change.

This is obviously wrong, but I'm not sure what to do instead.  (This is my first experience with Svelte.)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

Store the stock prices as a hash in a `writable()` store.

```js
// in stores.js
export const stocks = writable({})
```

Then when you want to update the price or add a new stock, you call `stocks.update()`.

```js
// in stores.js
export function update(symbol, data) {
  // using `...` to destructure a copy, we don't want to overwrite previous value
  stocks.update(({...records}) => { 
    // now update the copy
    records[symbol] = data

    // return the new value for the store, this will trigger updates in templates that subscribe 
    return records
  })
}
```

In your `.svelte` component, import the `store.js`

```html
<script>
  import {stocks, update} from './store.js'
  import {onMount} from 'svelte'

  update('AAPL', {ask: 10, bid: 20})
  update('MSFT', {ask: 10, bid: 20})

  onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(() => update('AAPL', {ask: 10.20, bid: 10.25}), 2000)
    setTimeout(() => update('AAPL', {ask: 10.30, bid: 10.35}), 4000)
  })
</script>

<!-- use dollar sign in front of store name to make svelte auto-subscribe -->

<pre>
  {JSON.stringify($stocks, null, 2)}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, @joshnuss. In the middle of the update function, should `records[symbol] = data` be changed to `quotes[symbol] = data`?  At least, that seemed necessary for me.

Comment: I don't think this actually addresses my concern about updating the entire page at once, does it?  If you subscribe to `$stocks`, you'll refresh the whole `<pre>` element anytime stocks changes, right?  I only want to update AAPL when AAPL gets an update and only update MSFT when MSFT gets an update.  How can I selectively subscribe at that level per symbol (without hard-coding symbols in the page, because I don't know what symbols the user will request)?

Comment: Have you measured the performance? Is it not acceptable? What is acceptable? What’s the bottleneck? Painting the DOM elements? I would measure before you refactor on a hunch.

Comment: I think this is a real limitation in Svelte. If you display stocks, you would probably want to also make some visual notification of the stock being updated, in case of binding to the whole store this is impossible (as all the values are updated).